# Pulling a random image from imgur with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I created a function with the help of some other StackOverflow answers - when the button is clicked, it generates a random image from imgur by using a 5-letter string and adding it to a url. Here's my code: http://codepen.io/kaisle/pen/ojbwQm

```
function randomString() {
    var chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    var stringlength = 5;
    var text = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < stringlength; i++) {
      var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
      text += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = text;
    var source = 'http://i.imgur.com/' + text + '.jpg';
    $('.stuff img').attr('src', source);
    var newimagewidth = $('.stuff img').width;
    avoidBrokenImages();
  }
```

This is successful besides the fact that I get the "removed" image a lot, because it's pulling deleted pictures from imgur, or images that never contained the random 5-letter string. To avoid this, I'm trying to create a way to detect this image (http://i.imgur.com/removed.png), which is 161px wide, and then re-run the function until it gets an image that is not 161px wide. I have attempted this in the Codepen above by running the following function at the end of my image generator function:

```
function avoidBrokenImages(){
  var newimagewidth = $('.stuff img').width;
  if ($('.stuff img').width() == 161) {
     randomString();
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

This "avoidBrokenImages" function doesn't seem to work because I'm still getting the "removed" image a lot.

Any suggestions? I feel like this is something easy I'm missing.

Comment: The function returns false, ok, but what do you expect to happen because that function returns false?

Comment: There are some characters missing : `var newimagewidth = $('.stuff img').width()`. Change that and you won't have to repeat it in the conditional statement. For the rest I'd go with the answer given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to read the image width before it's loaded.  You should change

```
$('.stuff img').attr('src', source);
var newimagewidth = $('.stuff img').width;
avoidBrokenImages();
```

to

```
$('.stuff img').attr('src', source).on('load', avoidBrokenImages);
```

Modified original: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qObPrq

Slightly cleaned up code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdVXWY

Comment: Using `load()` without `on()` for this purpose has been deprecated for a while. Might be better to make it `$('.stuff img').attr('src', source).on('load', avoidBrokenImages);`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer arcyqwerty. And Shikkediel, thanks, this does work even better using on( ), it seems to bypass the 161px images more quickly. Can you guys think of a way to not show the 161px images at all, maybe somehow checking the width before updating the source?

Comment: Yes, if you use JavaScript's `Image` object instead of using a DOM object.  You could also load it into an invisible DOM object first then swap it when you've found a match.

Comment: Updated http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdVXWY to use `Image` object.  As a note, if you want the text not to update until the image has been found, move the update statement to the `else` block where the image is replaced. :)

Comment: @Shikkediel: Thanks for the tip.  It's been a little while since I did frontend work.  Answer updated to use `on()` for the original code.